# If $A'∩B= A∩B'$ then what happens

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Okay so here's what I did:

$(A'∩B)\cup A'= (A∩B') \cup A'$

$A'=  A'\cup B'$

$A=A ∩B$

$A \subseteq B$

Is this correct? Like am I allowed to add $A'$ to both sides of the equation?
If so then $A\subseteq B$ which wouldn’t always be right.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why is the second equality true?

Comment: please, check the notations. It is unclear.

Comment: Does $A'$ designates the complementary set of $A$ ?

Comment: Your conclusion, $A \subseteq B$, is correct. And by symmetry, $B\subseteq A$. So we must have $A=B$.

Comment: @TonyK ohhhhh omg thank you I got it! Thanks so much!

Comment: If the equality holds then you can also go for: $A'\cap B=A'\cap B\cap A\cap B'=\varnothing$ and similarly $A\cap B'=\varnothing$. Final conclusion: $A=B$.

Comment: Well if $X = Y$ then $whateveryoudoto(X) = whateveryoudoto(Y)$ so yes $X\cup A = Y\cup A$.  But why do you think $(A'\cap B)\cup A'=A'$  (it does).  And why do you think $(A\cap B')\cup A'= A'\cup B'$?  You should go into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If x in A' $\cap$ B, then x in A' and since x in A $\cap$ B', x in A.
The contradiction shows A' $\cap$ B is empty.  Thus B subset A.
Likewise, A subset B.  A = B is what happens.